# How to use Kerberos to secure Solr admin panel on standalone installation?

Tags: solr, kerberos, apache-zookeeper

How can I use Kerberos to secure the Solr Admin panel on a standalone (non- Solr-Cloud) configuration? I've tried using https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Kerberos+Authentication+Plugin but I don't understand how to set up authentication without Zookeeper/security.json.

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the same wiki page you link to, you can specify you want to use the Kerberos Plugin as a Java System Property on node start up.

For example, in your solr.in.sh, you can add `SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_OPTS="-DauthenticationPlugin=org.apache.solr.security.KerberosPlugin"`. You'll need a JAAS config file as well as some additional properties as well, you can see these specified in the "Define a JAAS Configuration File" and "Solr Startup Parameters" sections on the same page.

Note: The `solr.kerberos.principal` you specify must be the SPNEGO SPN (i.e. HTTP/solr.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM) for the full qualified domain name of the host the Solr node is located on.

This is likely different to the service principal you use for the internode communication that you register in your JAAS config file (something like solr/solr.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM).